# How To Stop Polling InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Im polling files from 2 different directories in 1 server using  RotatingServerAdvice and that´s working fine, the problem is that I can´t stop polling once time I start the inboundtest.start (). The main idea is retrive all the files in those directories, and then send inboundtest.stop (), this is the code.

```
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        //factory.setTestSession(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectory);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(".*?\\.(txt|TXT?)"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }


    @Bean(name = "sftpMessageSource")
    @EndpointId("inboundtest")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel",poller = @Poller("fileReadingMessageSourcePollerMetadata"), autoStartup = "false")
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDirectoryDownloadUpload));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
        public DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory() {
            Map<Object, SessionFactory<LsEntry>> factories = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                factories.put("one", sftpSessionFactory());
            // use the first SF as the default
            return new DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factories, factories.values().iterator().next());
        }

    @Bean
    public RotatingServerAdvice advice() {
        List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
        keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("one", sftpRemoteDirectory));
        keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory("one", sftpRemoteDirectoryNonUpload));
        return new RotatingServerAdvice(sessionFactory(), keyDirectories, false);
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel controlChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    } 
 @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlChannel")
    ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() {
        return new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    } 

    @Bean
    public PollerMetadata fileReadingMessageSourcePollerMetadata() {
        PollerMetadata meta = new PollerMetadata();
        meta.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
        meta.setAdviceChain(List.of(advice()));
        meta.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
        meta.setErrorHandler(throwable -> new IOException());
        return meta;
    }
```

Allways is waiting for a new file in one of the 2 directories, but thats no the idea, the idea is stop polling when all the files be retrived

From another class I call inbound.start() trouhg the control chanel here the code:

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel controlChannel;

public void startProcessingFiles() throws InterruptedException {
    controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@inboundtest.start()"));
    
}
```

I was tryong stop with this class but doesn´t works

```
 @Component
public class StopPollingAdvice implements ReceiveMessageAdvice {

@Autowired
private MessageChannel controlChannel;



@Override
public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> message, Object o) {
    System.out.println("There is no more files, stopping connection" + message.getPayload());
    if(message == null) {
        System.out.println("There is no more files, stopping connection" + message.getPayload());
        Message operation = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@inboundtest.stop()").build();
       
        controlChannel.send(operation);
      
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

Comment: And how do your stop it, please? I see it is `autoStartup = "false"`, so you start it somehow. Show that one, please, and the code where you send this `inboundtest.stop()`

Comment: Sure! And same way you can call `stop()`. If you do that and it does not really stop, then something is off or just bug on our side…

Comment: Hello sorry I updated the answer and I added the code in there

Comment: For the stop I was trying creating a class that implements the ReceiveMessageAdvice interface, then I override the method affterRecive, and with this method I was sending a message with the inboundtest.sop() in the headers, this messahe travel trouhg the control channel too, then in my fileReadingMessageSourcePollerMetadata poller I was put an Advicechain passing like parameter an instance from the class that implements the ReceiveMessageAdvice  but that doesn´t function

Comment: So, that's the code you have to show us. Not sure how you would like to have a help if you really don't show the code which is crucial for your question.

Comment: Ready I updated the Question again with that part of the code

Comment: If `message == null`, is must fail with NPE on your SOUT sentence. So, indeed it cannot reach that `controlChannel.send()`. (Unless you show slightly modified code...)

Comment: If I use the class StopPollingAdvice doesn't work like I expected because stops after polling only one directory and doesn't poll from the sencod one

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the code you show so far does not work by definition. If message is null, then NPE is thrown from the first line of that method impl.

Comment: I removed the if message == null and then I passed the StopPollingAdvice as parameter just like this  
    `public PollerMetadata fileReadingMessageSourcePollerMetadata(StopPollingAdvice stopPollingAdvice) {
        PollerMetadata meta = new PollerMetadata();
        meta.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
        meta.setAdviceChain(List.of(advice()));
        meta.setAdviceChain(List.of(stopPollingAdvice));
        meta.setErrorHandler(throwable -> new IOException());
        return meta;
    }` but with this only retrive files from one dir and from the second one can't retrive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Now I see your point. The `RotatingServerAdvice` does move to other server only when the first is exhausted (by default, see that `fair` option). So, when you stop it in the advice it cannot go to other dir for fetching any more. You need to think about some other stopping solution. Something what is not tied to the advice and this `afterReceive()`, somewhere downstream in your flow...

Or you can provide a custom `RotationPolicy` (extension of `StandardRotationPolicy`) and in its overridden `afterReceive()` check for all the dirs processed and then send stop command.

Comment: Ok, please let me know if I understand the idea, something like this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WIyhS4M0dIOSCQ-oXNc4kGVoIHkMzSzl/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bkylvGMGMbfAWMoCMgGtwqxN14Vva_-a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, the logic is like that, although it is not clear how to track those dirs, but since you have accepted the answer, I believe you have figured it out.